# Undefined local variable or method `video_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following a tutorial on how to implement braintree but I run into an error, while trying to rake db:seed or in action#show:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `video_url' for #    <Movie:0x007ff0c9fd4028>
/.../.../.../tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/app/models/movie.rb:16:in `embed_video_url'
/.../.../.../tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/db/seeds.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/.../.../.../tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my seeds data: https://github.com/claucece/cartandbraintree/blob/purchase/db/seeds_data/movies.csv

And there is my movie model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :purchases
has_many :buyers, through: :purchases

before_save :embed_video_url

def poster
"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/#{poster_url}"
 end

def imdb
"http://www.imdb.com/title/#{imdb_id}/"
end

def embed_video_url
self.video_url = "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{video_url.split('v=') [1].split('&list')[0]}"
end

def cart_action(current_user_id)
if $redis.sismember "cart#{current_user_id}", id
  "Remove from"
else
  "Add to"
end
end
end
```

I think I'm missing something really easy.. but don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined local variable or method `video_url' for #    <Movie:0x007ff0c9fd4028>
```

This means, it can't find the `video_url` method for a movie object. Make sure your `movies` tables has a `vider_url` column in the database.

So, here is your schema:
https://github.com/claucece/cartandbraintree/blob/purchase/db/schema.rb#L14-L25

And, you don't have `video_url` in your `movies` table. That's why you got this error.

To solve this problem, you just need to create a migration to add the `video_url` column in your `movies` table.

```
rails generate migration AddVideoUrlToMovies video_url:string
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then, it will work as expected.